# Returning length of array after push in app function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following app function that stores data. Users can add new items and it returns the length of the data array.

I am trying to understand why returning the data in a function returns the data including the pushed items, but returning the `data.length` does not and neither does applying a filter.  If I request the data length outside of the app function scope, it does return it including the pushed items.

In my example,  `getfn` , `app.data.length` and `app.data.filter` returns the added items, but `getcntfn` and `filterinitialfn` does not. Why is this?

```js
var app = (function () {
        var data = ["initial"];

        function add(x) { data.push(x) }

        function getfn() { return data };
        function getcntfn() { return data.length };
        function filterinitialfn(filter) { return data.filter(x => x == filter) }

        return {
            add: function (x) { add(x) },
            data:data,
            getfn: getfn(),
            getcntfn: getcntfn(),
            filterinitialfn: function(filter) {filterinitialfn(filter)}
        }
    }());

    app.add("added")

    console.log("app.getfn", app.getfn)                                             //["initial", "added"]
    console.log("app.getcntfn", app.getcntfn)                                       //1  ???
    console.log("app.data.length", app.data.length)                                 //2
    console.log("app.filterinitialfn", app.filterinitialfn("added"))              //[]  ???
    console.log("app.filterinitial=>", app.data.filter(x => x == "added"))          //["added"]
```

Comment: You are creating `app` before adding, and `getfn`, `getcntfn`, `filterinitialfn` aren't functions (although you name them such, which is confusing), but the returns of them, and never change.

Comment: You are executing the functions in your return statement e.g. `getcntfn: getcntfn()`. You should not do this, otherwise the value will be whatever it was when the app function was created. You should use `getcntfn: getcntfn` (or just `getcntfn`), and later actually invoke the function e.g. `app.getcntfn()` instead of `app.getcntfn`.

Comment: I sort of gathered that it get executed immediately, but what throws me is the fact that 'getfn' does return the pushed item and 'getcntfn' does not, even though they are initiated the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, the result of `getfn: getfn()` is evaluated when being initialised, it wont' change the value when calling it.

You'll need to pass the function itself, without calling it so it's evaluated on the call:

```
getfn: getfn,
getcntfn: getcntfn,
...
```

Since all your functions have the same name as the return object key, we can use [the shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) to create the object:

```js
var app = (function () {
var data = ["initial"];

function add(x) { data.push(x) }
function getfn() { return data };
function getcntfn() { return data.length };
function filterinitialfn(filterBy) { return data.filter(x => x == "added") }
function filterBy(filterBy) { return data.filter(x => x == filterBy); }

return {
    add,
    data,
    getfn,
    getcntfn,
    filterinitialfn,
    filterBy
}
}());

app.add("added")

console.log("app.getfn", app.getfn())
console.log("app.getcntfn", app.getcntfn())
console.log("app.data.length", app.data.length)
console.log("app.filterinitialfn", app.filterinitialfn())
console.log("app.filterinitial=>", app.data.filter(x => x == "added"))
console.log("app.filterBy", app.filterBy('initial'))
```

Comment: Thanks that is very usefull. But say I still want to pass parameters to some of these for example the filter: ` var app = (function () {
var data = ["initial"];
function add(x) { data.push(x) }
function filterinitialfn(filter) { return data.filter(x => x == filter) }
return {
    add,
    filterinitialfn: function(filter) {filterinitialfn(filter)}
    }
}());
app.add("added")
console.log("app.filterinitialfn", app.filterinitialfn("initial")) `

Comment: You can pass function parameters as normal. Please see my edit, I've added a `filterBy` as example!

Comment: You are a rockstar. works like a charm and the shorthand tip will also save me lots of coding time.

Answer (score 2):

because you are calling the function immediately when returning it so it can't be changed from the initial state, so change it to:

```
return {
            add: function (x) { add(x) },
            data:data,
            getfn: getfn,
            getcntfn: getcntfn,
            filterinitialfn: filterinitialfn,
        }
```

of course, when using then you should include parentheses.